# Google App Engine Java not receiving email

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email

I followed the tutorial on here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/receiving

so I did all the following:

- declared `inbound-services`
- set up a handler servlet (with auth constraint)
- checked that everything works locally: `http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin/inboundmail`

but when I deploy, I can't send an email to my host. Why is this?

Note: I'm deploying on a separate version (`myname-dot-appengineproject`), so all of my emails have been: `something@myname-dot-appengineproject.appspotmail.com` but this shouldn't matter, right? (do I have to deploy to the default vrsion?)

I have billing enabled. (is there some extra settings I have to turn on? I can't find the settings that would indicate if email is sent on or not.)

Answer (score 1):

OH wow that was retarded. the services declaration is actually in `appengine-web.xml`, NOT `web.xml`

```
<inbound-services>
    <service>mail</service>
</inbound-services>
```

definitely mis-read that.

the other reason i was confused is because for some reason, my logs didn't appear when processing from a mail request

not sure if default version matters or not

Answer (score 0):

Mail services works on the default version. Please point your application to the default one or change this to default one. It should work.

Comment: but what if i want to make sure it works before deploying to default version?

Comment: also, i just tried this on the default module but it didn't work.